# Go-style channels in C

Tags: c, multithreading, go, signal-processing

For a real time DSP program in C, I need something like Go-style channels to communicate between threads:

- One thread pushes tokens on the channel
- Another thread pulls tokens from the channel
- The channel has a buffer
- In my case, tokens have a small memory footprint (small vectors of numbers)

I was wondering if using good old streams was a good idea, or not. If not, is there a good practice and/or a library to get something as close as Go channels as possible?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Go channels, but from your description I think you should have a look at zeromq inproc sockets https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq

Comment: @dkrikun Actually in my case everything remains within one process (for efficiency reasons, I think these channels have to work with shared memory). So message queuing solutions might be "too much".

Comment: zeromq has *inproc* socket kind which use process memory, no tcp or even interprocess shared memory.

Comment: Closest I know is the thread library included with plan9port, but I don't think it's written for real time applications, so you'll probably have to modify it somewhat

Comment: @dkrikun zeromq in-proc is exactly what I need thanks! That being said if there is something more lightweight (since I don't need 90% of zeromq), it would be great.

Comment: You could always just use a sychronized spmc fifo with a sempahore to wake the other thread.  See http://concurrencykit.org for lots of awesome concurrent primitives.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing describes a thread-safe *queue*.

The Apache Project has [one implementation](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr-util/1.3/apr__queue_8h.html). GLib has [another implementation](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/struct.AsyncQueue.html).

Other than that, a lot of users have actually shared their `pthread` queue implementations, assuming that was what you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Go supports both buffered and unbuffered channels; unbuffered channels actually correspond to a "rendezvous" between two threads, which allows the threads to directly exchange data, i.e. without requiring an additional buffer; thread rendezvous can be implemented e.g. with a barrier (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_(computer_science)). Your small, fixed-size tokens seem well suited for the unbuffered approach.

Buffered channels in contrast can be implemented as thread-safe queues, as already mentioned. In FreeRTOS you can e.g. use xQueueCreate to create such a queue.

I recently implemented a C library which supports the semantics of buffered as well as unbuffered Go channels based on Pthreads (see https://github.com/rochus-keller/CspChan). You didn't provide information about your implementation environment. Porting the library to FreeRTOS (or similar low-level operating systems) looks feasible though.